# Searching an array for the lastIndexOf where class property is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, lastindexof

I have an array of classes which all have a property of isPurchased, I want to return the last item in the array which has the value set to true.

```
function ShopItem = new function(id, name, isPurchased) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isPurchased = isPurchased;
}    

var apple = ShopItem(1, "Apple", false);
var banana = ShopItem(2, "Banana", true);
var pear = ShopItem(3, "Pear", false);

var shopItems = [apple, banana, pear];

var x = shopItems.lastIndexOf(this.isPurchased == true);
console.log(x);
```

When I do console.log(x); I want it to return the banana class.

Everything works fine until I try to find the last item and for this I tried to use:

```
var x = shopItems.lastIndexOf(this.isPurchased == true);
```

But it returns -1.

Edit:

I have a way to solve the solution by using the code:

```
var y = null;

for(var o in shopItems) {
    if(shopItems[o].isPurchased == true) {
        y = shopItems[o];
    }
}

console.log(y);
```

But if lastIndexOf can solve my problem for me then I would rather use that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `lastIndexOf` searches for a fixed value. It doesn't accept a condition (proper term: predicate), and even if it did you don't specify predicates that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastIndexOf` searches for values and doesn’t check conditions, plus `this.isPurchased == true` is an expression, not a lambda. It’d be akin to checking `shopItems.lastIndexOf(true)`. This isn’t built into JavaScript (not even in ES6, which offers `Array.prototype.find[Index]` but not `findLast`), so you’ll have to build it yourself:

```
function findLast(items, predicate) {
    for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var item = items[i];

        if (predicate(item)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it with a function to call back:

```
var x = findLast(shopItems, function (item) {
    return item.isPurchased;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I prefer this method to do what I needed to do.